# Mask RGBA image with another one

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Consider there are two opencv images / numpy arrays of different shapes.
Smaller one is called `small` and is `(150,150,4)`, bigger one is called `big` and is `(300,300,4)`, both are RGBA images.
I'm trying to get the smaller one to be "on top" of the bigger one, exactly in the middle (this is done and works fine), but I need only the pixels of the smaller one, which are not transparent (their alpha channel is not equal 0, or is equal 255 to be exact), otherwise I want to keep the pixels from the bigger one (and this is the issue). Something like a ternary operator, but with broadcasting and in numpy/opencv. I thought of `np.where` and masking, but got stuck.
I know how to get the `mask` of my smaller shape, but I don't know how to properly assign / broadcast it into the bigger one.

My approach is:

- get the rectangle where the assignment should take place (offsets)
- get the mask of the smaller one, to have only the shape's coordinates
- **assign / broadcast the pixels** - The problem is I need pixel values of corresponding coordinates of the bigger image, not a single value. The part I'm missing, currently using some dummy value
- assign the modified smaller one into the coordinates of the bigger one

```py
BACKGROUND_SIZE = 300, 300
LOGO_SIZE = 150, 150

def get_offset(bigger_shape, smaller_shape):
    logo_x_offset = int((bigger_shape[0] - smaller_shape[0]) / 2)
    logo_y_offset = int((bigger_shape[1] - smaller_shape[1]) / 2)
    return (
        logo_y_offset,
        logo_y_offset + smaller_shape[1],
        logo_x_offset,
        logo_x_offset + smaller_shape[0],
    )


small = cv2.imread(f"./small.png", flags=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
big =  cv2.imread(f"./big.png", flags=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
offset = get_offset(BACKGROUND_SIZE, LOGO_SIZE)
y0, y1, x0, x1 = offset

DUMMY_BLUE = (255,0,0,255)
mask = np.where(small[:, :, 3] != 255) # this is a proper mask
small[mask] = DUMMY_BLUE # Here instead of the dummy blue I need the "bigger" image pixels 
bigger[y0:y1, x0:x1] = smaller
```

Tried:

```py
 small[mask] = big[y0:y1, x0:x1]
```

But that fails with (please ignore the 2nd shape, the `big` might be actually bigger):

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (150,150,4) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (14899,4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by multiplying by your small image by the mask, then adding:

```
mask = small[:, :, 3] == 255
small *= mask[:, :, None]
big[y0:y1, x0:x1] *= 1 - mask[:, :, None]
big[y0:y1, x0:x1] += small
```

Comment: Tried it, got: `numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('int64') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind'`, but used `small = small * mask[:,:,None]` and the same for 2nd multiply and it worked. Kudos, that's the correct way to go,:)

Comment: One question though, what is `None` doing when indexing np.arrays. I haven't work in numpy for years.

Comment: Adding the `None` is kind of manually giving a hint for broadcasting, as it expands the axis with a singleton dimension. There is an alias `np.newaxis` but it's longer to type :). This is needed because numpy broadcasting starts from the rightmost dimensions.

Comment: Good call on the casting exception - this was not a problem for me because I was just using random arrays instead of reading in images.